# How can I make a "self-referential" replacement operation self-contained?

Tags: functions, programming, replacement, recursion, pure-function

Fairly often I find use for replacement rules that call themselves on the right-hand side of the rule, e.g.:

```
rule = {p___, a, b, c, q___} :> Join[{p, "abc"}, {q} /. rule];
```

Unfortunately this makes the rule dependent on the specific definition of the Symbol `rule`; it can no longer be copied and modified as an independent expression.  Ideally I would like to use the `#0` syntax for [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) to call the replacement but the most direct application does not work:

```
# /. {p___, a, b, c, q___} :> Join[{p, "abc"}, #0 @ {q}] & @ "x"
```

> RuleDelayed::rhs: Pattern p___ appears on the right-hand side of rule {p___,a,b,c,q___}:>Join[{p,abc},(#1/. {p___,a,b,c,q___}:>Join[{p,abc},#0[{<<1>>}]]&)[{q}]]. >>

Due to the specific mechanism of `#0` its substitution cannot be delayed using e.g. `Slot @@ {0}`; the substitution will never occur.

The only pseudo-solution I have found is to move `#0` out of the RHS of the rule, then substitute it using another replacement:

```
# /. {p___, a, b, c, q___} :> "Join"[{p, "abc"}, "#0" @ {q}] /. {"Join" -> Join, "#0" -> #0} & @
 {1, 2, a, b, c, 3, {4, a, b, c}, 5}
```

> ```
>  {1, 2, "abc", 3, {4, "abc"}, 5}
> ```

However this destroys the purpose of my construct which was to avoid repeatedly scanning from the beginning of the expression.  (There are other uses for self-referential replacement but I believe they are all seriously degraded by this "solution.")  It is also fragile to use replacement of `"Join"` and `"#0"` so additional complexity or dependency would be required.

Is there some other way I can shield the replacement rule (substituted for `#0`) from itself without changing the replacement traversal of the expression?

Is there an approach not involving `#0` to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
foo = With[{f = #0}, (# /. {p___, a, b, c, q___} :> Join[{p, "abc"}, f @ {q}])] &

lst = {1, 2, a, b, c, 3, {4, a, b, c}, 5};
foo@lst
(* {1, 2, "abc", 3, {4, "abc"}, 5} *)
```

This works because `With` automatically renames the patterns used in `RuleDelayed` since both are scoping constructs.  Other constructs can be used as well such as `RuleDelayed` itself:

```
#0 /. f_ :> (# /. {p___, a, b, c, q___} :> Join[{p, "abc"}, f @ {q}]) & @
 {1, 2, a, b, c, 3, {4, a, b, c}, 5}

(* {1, 2, "abc", 3, {4, "abc"}, 5} *)
```

To further illustrate here is an excerpt from [`TracePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TracePrint.html) on the first application above:

```
 {1, 2, a, b, c, 3, {4, a, b, c}, 5} /. {p$___, a, b, c, q$___} :> 
  Join[{p$, "abc"}, (With[{f = #0}, #1 /. {p___,a,b,c,q___} :> Join[{p, "abc"}, f[{q}]]]&)[{q$}]]
```

Comment: Thanks for solving this for me.  I wish I had seen the solution myself but it didn't even cross my mind.

Comment: @kguler You make me speechless :) Just for curiousity: How could a solution for this brainteaser look like without the `Replace`-family ?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, my pleasure. I will need 24-48 hours to digest your new construct:)

Comment: @eldo I don't think I understand what you mean.  Replace without using `Replace`?  What's the point of that?

Comment: @kguler It's exactly the same as your construct except that I used `/.` instead of `With` which does the same thing here, even the renaming.

Comment: @eldo thank you for the compliment! Not sure i understand "without the Replace-family" -- you mean a memoization-like trick in function definition to do the same replacement?

Comment: @kguler I just meant: Could one get the desired result without `Replace`, `ReplaceAll`, `ReplaceList` ? Well, it's probably quite another question, and I don't want you to get too involved with a comment.